# The Inner Join is returning result from only one table instead of both tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

```
SELECT InvoiceNo as [Invoice No],
       SUM(Quantity) as Quantity,
       SUM(TaxableAmt) as Taxable_Amount,
       SUM(CGSTAmt) as CGST_Amount,
       SUM(SGSTAmt) as SGST_Amount,
       SUM(Amount) as Amount 
FROM tbl_PurchaseDetails    
INNER JOIN tbl_CUSTOMERMASTER 
  ON tbl_CUSTOMERMASTER.PartyID = tbl_PurchaseDetails.PartyID     
GROUP BY tbl_PurchaseDetails.InvoiceNo
```

The above query is returning result from only one table while I want result from both tables.

It is displaying result like this:

[image]

While I want my result like this:

[image]

Comment: You need to either add your other columns to the GROUP BY or aggregate them in the SELECT.

Comment: In your select list you have selected only columns from one table so you are getting the result like that, In order to get the result from both tables you need to select accordingly

Comment: Thanks it worked...